# How to break-up time periods based on the start & end times of other time periods

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, timeline, gantt-chart

Unfortunately I have come across a problem I can not solve. Hopefully someone here can help me!

I have one dataset, which includes several tasks that are performed partially parallel.
I would like to get rid of parallel tasks, for which I feel like I need to first break-up all tasks so the end of one task is the start of another (without losing any data).

As an example, task A is from 01:00-02:00 and task B is from 01:30-02:30, I believe I first need to turn these two tasks into four tasks:

```
A: 01:00-01:30  
A: 01:30-02:00  
B: 01:30-02:00  
B: 02:00-02:30
```

However, knowing what to do is one thing, I'm not succeeding at doing it.
Any suggestions on how to perform this explosion/break-up of tasks?

This is part of the data I'm using:

```
Task    Start   End Priority  
1   00:00:00    01:00:00    1  
2   00:45:00    01:30:00    3  
3   02:00:00    02:30:00    2  
4   01:00:00    03:30:00    4  
5   03:00:00    04:00:00    2
```

Which I hope to turn into:

```
Task #  Start   End Priority  
1   00:00:00    00:45:00    1  
1   00:45:00    01:00:00    1  
2   00:45:00    01:00:00    3  
2   01:00:00    01:30:00    3  
4   01:00:00    01:30:00    3  
4   01:30:00    02:00:00    4  
3   02:00:00    02:30:00    2  
4   02:00:00    02:30:00    4  
4   02:30:00    03:00:00    4  
4   03:00:00    03:30:00    4  
5   03:00:00    03:30:00    2  
5   03:30:00    04:00:00    2
```

I've added a screenshot of how the broken-up tasks could look like.

I've exploded my data, by appending the start and end times of each task to eachother. So I would have 5x task 1 where the final two columns contained the start and end time of task 2, 3, 4 and 5.

```
1   00:00:00    01:00:00    1   00:45:00    01:00:00  
1   00:00:00    01:00:00    1   01:00:00    01:30:00  
1       etc  
1  
1
```

After doing this I tried to get extract all possible combinations of timestamps.
Such as 00:00 - 00:45 and 00:45-01:00

This was not successful however, as some tasks started both earlier and ended later than other tasks.. There I lost it.